# How to map a model's integer attribute to a string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a Hotels table in my database, and one of the columns is `:status` (`integer`). I'm looking to convert these integers into strings, so `1 = "Awaiting Contract"`, `2 = "Designing"` and so on...

I have searched Stack for some answers, and the lack of them makes me think that I'm coming at this problem from the wrong angle? I used to do this in PHP whilst pulling the data. New-ish to Rails so any help, or best practise advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check `enum` of `ActiveRecord` - [doc](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html).

Here you can configure your `:status`:

```
class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: { waiting_contract: 1, designing: 2 }

  def format_status
    status.to_s.humanize
  end
end
```

It'll create methods like this:

```
hotel.waiting_contract?
hotel.designing?

hotel.waiting_contract!
hotel.format_status # => "Waiting contract"
```

Hope that helps!

**UPDATE**

Similar functionality might be achieved by overriding the `status` method itself, although having separate methods is more advised:

```
class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: { waiting_contract: 1, designing: 2 }

  def status
    super.to_s.humanize
  end
end
```

Furthermore, [decorators](https://github.com/drapergem/draper) are something you should look into for view-specific methods.

Comment: What would be the "better looking" string way? Add a method to the model that returns strings based on the status codes?

Comment: if hotel status is "waiting contract" (`hotel.waiting_contract!`), when asked for status "waiting_contract" will be returned - `hotel.status # => "waiting_contract"`, but in templates "Waiting Contract" would be expected... I'll update answer with some suggestion to this

Comment: @PawełDawczak, it would be a good idea to mention the possiblity to override `status` using `super.to_s.humanize` in the new method's body. although, the wiser option would be indeed to have separate methods. and to shift view-specific methods to decorators.

Comment: @Humza - I did not recommend overwriting "original" `status` only because of personal preference (experience?). In my code I'd rather avoid this approach (what if in future I would need "original" output of `status` method? I'd break every occurrence in my current code). However, it's worth mentioning it is possible and completely valid code!

Comment: @PawełDawczak Agree with you completely but felt it necessary to point out the possibility to the OP

Comment: @PawełDawczak Thankyou! I agree, sometimes I'll wait to humanise, but not at all times. Plus other devs on my team would also like the preference. Great example.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you need the list for. An alternative to the above ideas, is to create a hash. Hashes are very Ruby and designed just for this sort of paired data.

Create the hash, (enumeration typing is automatic.)

```
   my_h = { "waiting" => 1, "design" => 2 }
```

Then to access

```
my_h["waiting"] = 1
```

There's much more you can do with hashes. This is just the simplest case.

A hash may or not fulfill your needs, but it's a splendid tool that comes with a nice set of Ruby worker methods.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html